# What is the minimum sequence length that can be used with the LSTM model for sequence classification?

Tags: time-series, lstm, sequential-pattern-mining

the sequence is time-series data. It is possible to use as sequence length even low values such as 5 or 10?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they definitely can be used. You will still enjoy many of the advantages (e.g. built-in sequentiality, increased gradient flow to early timesteps) even with relatively few timesteps. E.g. with 10 timesteps, a vanilla RNN still has to backpropogate the gradient through (at least) 10 layers. An LSTM will likely train a lot faster.

That being said, the advantages of LSTMs will in general become much more apparent as the number of timesteps increases.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe a bit out of topic but you may help me to understand.. is the LSTM model able to understand the dependencies or sequencialities between the sequences (each of sequence_lenght number of timesteps)?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking... It is capable of (and in fact designed to) recognize sequential patterns within a given sequence. But if you give it two different sequences (e.g. one sequence for day N, then a second sequence for day N+1), it will not be able to make meaningful inferences based on the relationship between these two sequences. To do this, you would need to instead double the size of your input sequence (in this example, to take two whole days of data).

Comment: yes you got the point, thank you!